# HTML web browser compatibility (IE8, Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, browser

I'm an embedded programmer.
I'm developing a web GUI, and having a problem - web browser compatibility.

The code is executing normally in Chrome, but not in Internet Explore.

After Internet Explorer 8, must to execute to code.

I think it is a Web Standard problem. Perhaps my HTML knowledge is very poor.

```
  function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["form_dl_rf_set"]["DL_RF_2000_id"].value;
    if (x == 1) {
      var y = document.forms["form_dl_rf_set"]["DL_RF_2000_num"].value;
      if (!y) {
         alert("error ");
         return false;
      }
    }
  }

  <form name="form_dl_rf_set" action="dl_rf_set.cgi" method=post onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <input type="radio" id="DL_RF_2000" name="DL_RF_2000_id" value="0"checked="checked">
  <label for="DL_RF_2000">変更しない<label>
  <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="radio" id="DL_RF_2000" name="DL_RF_2000_id" value="1">
  <label for="DL_RF_2000">&nbsp;<input type="number" id="DL_RF_2000" name="DL_RF_2000_num" min="-10.0" max="2.0" step="0.5" size="4" value=-1.0>&nbsp;dB</label>
```

Function description - check for blank.

Comment: What errors is IE reporting in the Inspector?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues I see, the first of which is IDs need to be unique ...

Try ...

```
<form name="form_dl_rf_set" action="dl_rf_set.cgi" method=post onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input type="radio" id="DL_RF_2000_id" name="DL_RF_2000_id1" value="0" checked="checked" />
    <label for="DL_RF_2000">変更しない</label>
    <input type="radio" id="DL_RF_2000_id2" name="DL_RF_2000_id2" value="1" />
    <label for="DL_RF_2000">&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="number" id="DL_RF_2000_num" name="DL_RF_2000_num" min="-10.0" max="2.0" step="0.5" size="4" value="-1.0">&nbsp;dB
```

I also cleaned up some close tag issues (and dropped the `<td>` tag since it didn't seem to need to be there.

Note that ALL the tags now have unique IDs which can now be referenced cleanly.

**UPDATE**:
One other issue I see is the repeated use of the names.  This has also been adjusted in the code above.

Also, there was a value with no quotes.

Comment: The IDs are irrelevant, the OP is accessing the form controls by name.

Comment: thanks for your reply. my code is not all web page source. td tag is not problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment, not an answer, since it's impossible to determine the issue from the OP. Hopefully it will help toward finding the issue so that an answer can be provided.

The posted code is incomplete, there is no submit button or way to submit the form. Adding a submit button fixes that, but perhaps not in a way that is consistent with the actual code.

In the *validateForm* function, there is:

```
    var x = document.forms["form_dl_rf_set"]["DL_RF_2000_id"].value;
```

There are multiple controls in the form with a name of 'DL_RF_2000_id', therefore the expression:

```
document.forms["form_dl_rf_set"]["DL_RF_2000_id"]
```

will return a [*NodeList*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177) of those elements. NodeLists don't have a *value* property, so *x* will be undefined. Then there is:

```
if (x == 1)
```

which will always be false, so the function returns *undefined* and the form is submitted. This will happen in all browsers, not just IE.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I don't know that if(x==1). I will modify to that. thanks.